# copying data from one table to another except the Identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity-column

Is there any way to copy all column values from one table to another except the `Identity` column, without mentioning all the rest of the column names?

I have a table with 63 columns. I created a temporary table with -

```
SELECT * INTO #TmpWide FROM WideTable WHERE 1 = 0
```

Now I want to copy some data from WideTable to #TmpWide. I need all the columns of WideTable except the `Identity` Id column, because I want the copied data to have their own sequential Id's in #TmpWide from 1 to onward. Is it possible without mentioning the (63-1) column names?

Answer (score 1):

You could try dropping the column after the table is created:

```
SELECT * INTO #TmpWide FROM WideTable WHERE 1=0
ALTER TABLE #TmpWide DROP COLUMN [Id]
```

This does feel a little ugly or hack-y, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I already tried that trick. Dropped the column, copied the data, then added a new Identity column - gave me *exactly* what i need. But it seems to have an impact on overall performance of the SP.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do that, but also it is a bad idea to use * in a situation like this. If WideTable changes you will be forced to change the stored procedures that SELECT * from it. I wrote hundreds of stored procs like this and all it did was create nightmares I'm still dealing with today. Good luck.

Comment: In this specific case, after processing data in #TmpWide they will be copied back to WideTable. So, I don't think changing WideTable will cause any trouble. But thanks a lot anyway. Definitely a valuable tip for other scenarios.